# Dockerfile alpine not installing the specific version

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am having a DockerFile where after twistlock scan, it is showing vulnerabilities in openssl version 1.1.1g-r0. So, I change the version to 1.1.1k-r0 where it is again showing the old version only. The new version is not reflecting at all.

```
FROM [PATH]/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u265-b01-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
    openssl=1.1.1k-r0 \
    busybox=1.31.1-r20 \
    musl=1.1.24-r10 \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

What is wrong with this DockerFile?

Comment: did you find any fix to this. I am facing the same error now